# Server Error in '/ccnet' Application

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, appsettings

My CCTray says build is broken and on the server(http://172.25.165.10/ccnet/)
I get this error

Server Error in '/ccnet' Application.

Configuration Error

```html
  <cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. 
       Add your projects below! -->

  <project name="winapp"
           description="demoproject showing a small config" queue="Q1">
    <webURL>http://172.25.165.10/ccnet/</webURL>
    <!-- specify a state folder to prevent CCNet from saving it in Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server 
      programs may not standard write their data in it on windows Vista and up)
    -->

    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>https://citdevbox.arcade.local:8443/svn/cardwellR/trunk/winapp</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>c:\builds\winapp</workingDirectory>
      <username>***</username>
      <password>***</password>
    </sourcecontrol>
    
    
    <state type="state" directory="C:\CCNet\State" />


    <!-- specify a artifactDirectory to prevent CCNet from saving it in Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server 
      programs may not standard write their data in it on windows Vista and up)
    -->
    <artifactDirectory>C:\CCNet\BuildArtifacts\MyFirstProject</artifactDirectory>

    <tasks>
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <projectFile>C:\Builds\build\BootStrapper.msbuild</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /t:CTSx86;BuildZip /v:d</buildArgs>
        <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        <timeout>900</timeout>
      </msbuild>
    </tasks>
    

    <triggers>
      <!-- check the source control every X time for changes, 
      and run the tasks if changes are found -->
      <intervalTrigger
               name="continuous"
               seconds="300"
               buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
               initialSeconds="5"/>
    </triggers>

   
    <publishers>
      <xmllogger />
      <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                       cleanUpValue="50" />
    </publishers>

  </project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message: The root element must match the name of the section referencing the file, 'appSettings'**

Source Error:

**Line 1:  cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"**

Source File: C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the content of your ccnet.config file which the error you are getting is complaining about.  Lets start with the obvious.  I would look to see if there is a typo in there, for example maybe a missing quote or something in the appSettings section.  If you have the unmodified version revert back to that and see if your issue goes away and compare the unmodified with the modified.

Comment: There is also a ccnet.exe.config in the same directory with an appSettings section any thing in there changed?

Comment: Nothing Changed in that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called CCValidator which will tell you where the error is in your `ccnet.config` file. I suspect that is not where the problem is. It sounds like the error is in the `ccservice.exe.config`. Perhaps someone accidentally copied `ccnet.config` to `ccservice.exe.config`. The error may also be in your web dashboard's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the build args tag.

</noconsolelogger /t:CTS**x86**;BuildZip /v:d>

My processor was 64 bit and I was using **noconsolelogger /t:CTSx86** which is for a 32 bit processor. Anyway these were optional so I removed it worked fine.